FFT Filter design
How to create an FFT filter (lets say, a band-pass) as been asked here before (e.g. Running an FFT filter on a large data set) but (I guess) given the questioner inexperience in digital filter design the question was answered with an alternative (e.g. FIR with overlap-add design).
So, in my case, I really need a FFT filter design since I'm designing a system with multiple channels and where the start/stop frequencies of each channel can change over time.
I understand that the main difficulty is when splitting the input data into several chunks and then "combining" the filtered chunks and performing the IFFT the "last samples" must somehow overlap-add with the "first samples" of the next chunk. Additionally, I believe some kind of windowing may be required.
However, I've search for some literature explaining how this method could be used but so far without much success. So I would like either an explanation of how to perform filters in the frequency domain over multiple chunks or a link/book/whatever that explains how this could be performed.
Edit 1: By FFT Filter I mean to calculate the DFT of the input signal, zero out the frequencies I don't want and convert it back to time domain.
Edit 2: I realize, even in my case, there could be "better ways" of solving this problem. But for the purpose of this question lets stay focus only on the "FFT Filter" solution please. Is there a book/whatever that explains how could this be done?

Time variant frequency domain processing is mathematically VERY complicated, so you need a good reason to go there. If all you need is a bandpass with time-varying cutoff frequencies, there are much easier methods available.

Filtering does not need to use the FFT to do it.  But if the filter is an FIR and if the impulse response is quite long, then implementing this long FIR conventionally (without the FFT) might require too many computations.  Then the FFT is employed in an operation called "fast convolution" that uses either Overlap-Add (OLA) or Overlap-Scrap (sometimes called "Overlap-Save" or OLS).  Is that what you mean by an "FFT filter"?

@Hilmar , if you're doing Overlap-Add fast convolution, you can simply adjust the frequency-domain representation of the FIR filter as long as you know the adjusted one is an FIR filter of the same length. In the overlapping regions where a "chunk" is overlapping the following chunk, it will be the trailing tail of the old FIR added to the rising tail of the new FIR. It's almost like a linear crossfade, but not exactly that either. But if you were using Overlap-Scrap (OLS), then you would have a jump discontinuity each frame boundary.  So OLS should not be used for time-varying FIR filters.

@robertbristow-johnson: the tricky bit is that whatever you have in the frequency domain needs be zero in the second half of the time domain or you get time domain aliasing. In other words the odd FFT bins are not independent but must be properly interpolated from the even FFT bins (which zero padding in the time domain does). That's hard /expensive to do in real time hence most version that I have seen get creative with analysis/synthesis windows, frame size, hop size and put some speed brakes on how fast bin amplitudes can move.

@robertbristow-johnson An "FFT filter" is (what I mean by it) to calculate the DFT of the input signal, zero out the frequencies that I "don't want" and convert it back to time domain. This works fine with only one big set of data but splitting the data into chuncks adds some problems. I believe I have to window it in the frequency domain (since a rectangular window is an infinite time sinc). I don't mean to be rude, but folks are focusing more on giving alternatives rather than pointing out how could this be done. Is there not a book that explains this?

What you're doing (or trying to do) @mabeco is actually what we call "fast convolution", but you have some details you need to worry about.  You cannot just zero out individual frequency bins that you don't want.  Zeroing out bins is the equivalent to multiplying by zero.  Multiplying in the frequency domain of the DFT is the same as circular convolution in the time domain.  You need to read about and understand what we mean by "Overlap-Add" and the "Overlap-Scrap" (or "Overlap-Save") methods.  You need to do this to avoid aliasing in the time domain which causes distortion.

//" the tricky bit is that whatever you have in the frequency domain needs be zero in the second half of the time domain or you get time domain aliasing."// - - - - @Hilmar I understand that.  But you don't have to divide it into two equal segments.  In fact, that's usually inefficient.  You want your FFT length to be much longer than twice the length of the FIR.  Still, if you Overlap-Add, you won't get a jump discontinuity if you shift from one $H[k]$ to another between frames.


FIR with overlap-add design

That is typically an FFT-based filtering approach, not an alternative to one. You might be confusing things.

So, in my case, I really need a FFT filter design since I'm designing a system with multiple channels and where the start/stop frequencies of each channel can change over time.

It doesn't matter in which domain you define a filter. So, no, you don't need any specific designer for an FFT filter. "FFT filter" is an implementation detail, not relevant to the filter shape.

I understand that the main difficulty is when splitting the input data into several chunks and then "combining" the filtered chunks and performing the IFFT the "last samples" must somehow overlap-add with the "first samples" of the next chunk. Additionally, I believe some kind of windowing may be required.

But that's just the general architecture, the algorithm, of how to implement an FFT filtering, which convolves an input signal with filter coefficients. The coefficients, i.e., what one calls "filter design", are separate from that issue.
So, I think you might be running into research problems, because you "abuse" the term "filter design" to mean something else than the rest of us would mean.
So, regarding "how do I implement a time-variant FFT-based filtering system": Done that before to emulate a time-variant channel (for a powerline communications emulator), through interpolation, simply by having twice as many parallel operating filters, and "blending over" from one filter to the other during operation (i.e., weigh the outputs of the first filter with $\alpha \in [0;1]$; weigh the output of the other filter with $1-\alpha$, sum them). You can exchange the coefficients of the filter that currently has weight 0 without affecting the system.
That's by far not the only way to smoothly transition between different filters with different filter states, and it will not be appropriate for all situations. But if you insist on frequency-domain filtering, a smoother "point-wise" convergence from one filter state to another is not possible (unless you throw away all the computational advantages of doing the filtering in frequency domain, by constantly transforming things back to the time domain).
The question that you should really answer here is how you come from

I'm designing a system with multiple channels and where the start/stop frequencies of each channel can change over time.

to

I really need a FFT filter,

because there's no causal link between these two statements – actually, you needing to change things temporally suggests you should do the opposite and stick with time-domain filtering.
You should explain what your requirement

start/stop frequencies of each channel can change over time,

really means in detail. I think there's a few misconceptions baked into your question, but I don't really know. A new question, describing the system you need to build, in detail, including rates, the hardware you're doing this on, the channel bandwidths, transition widths and points at which things change and how they need to change would make for an excellent new post!
